# rsync でサブディレクトリの構造も維持したままコピーしたい

Tags: rsync

rsync でコピー元を複数指定した際、コピー先と同じ階層にコピーするには、どうしたらいいのでしょうか。

例として、下記のようなコマンドを実行しました。
※「xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx」には、コピー先端末のIPアドレスが入ります。

```
rsync -rtlzvogpHAXP \
    /DirA/Dir1 \
    /DirA/Dir3 \
    /DirB/Dir1 \
    /DirC/Dir2 \
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/
```

上記のようなコマンドでコピーすると、「/」の下に「Dir1」、「Dir2」、「Dir3」ディレクトリが作成されてしまいます。

期待している動作としては、下記のようにコピー先と同じディレクトリ構造としてコピーしたいと考えています。

```
/DirA/Dir1
/DirA/Dir3
/DirB/Dir1
/DirC/Dir2
```

このようにディレクトリ構造を維持しつつコピーするには、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
何かよい方法があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-Rオプションを追加することで、意図された動作になるように思います。

Comment: 「-R」オプションでうまくいきました。アドバイスありがとうございました。